# Error al intentar hacer hover en una imagen en react hooks dentro de un Foreach

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

tengo un problema al intentar hacer aparecer una sombra cuando pase el mouse sobre
la imagen , el problema es que estas imagenes vienen de una lista la cual hago un map .

Aqui mi codigo

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import intialState from '../../intialState';
import '../../styles/components/banner.css';


const Banner = () => {
    const home = intialState.itemsHome;
    const [inHover, setHover] = useState(false);
    return (
        
        <div className="container h-100" >
            <div className="row align-middle">
            {home.map((items)=>{
               return <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 column">
                    <div class="card gr-1" style={{position:'absolute'}}>
                     
                            <img src={items.src} id={items.id} className="image"  onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}/>
                             {inHover && <div id={"mask"+items.id} className="info" style={{position:'absolute'}}></div>}
                             
                            
            
                       
                    </div>  
                </div>  

             }) } 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Banner;
```

siendo img la imagen que viene src del foreach y el hover el que tiene la clase info, porfa si alguien me puede ayudar con esto o como se puede utilizar de manera correcta el tema del state en dentro del foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví poniendo la funcion onMouseEnter y onMouseLeave en el div que contenia todo lo que se mapeaba a cada item , el error es que este hover se hacia en la imagen y por el color no se podia observarla , ademas adicione que se seleccionara cada imagen mapeada  mandando el id en vez del bool en el useState esto permite que valide cada uno de los cuadros mapeados y aparezca la sombra en el seleccionado aquí el código de la solución.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import intialState from '../../intialState';
import '../styles/components/banner.css';


const Banner = () => {
    const home = intialState.itemsHome;
    const [inHover, setHover] = useState(false);
    return (
        
        <div className="container h-100" >
            <div className="row align-middle">
            {home.map((items)=>{

               return (<div  class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 column"  onMouseEnter={() => setHover(items.id)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)} >
               <div    class="card gr-1" style={{position:'absolute'}} >
                
                       <img   src={items.src} style={{position:'absolute'}}  className="image"  />
                       {inHover === items.id && <div id={items.id} className="info" style={{position:'absolute'}}></div>}   
                        
                       
       
                  
               </div>  
           </div>  );
               

             }) } 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Banner;
```

Answer (score 1):

> No puedo realizar un comentario que es lo que realmente debería prueba [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365233/inline-css-styles-in-react-how-to-implement-ahover) está muy bien y funciona

Comment: un consejo utiliza el hook useRef, para múltiples elementos y agrega un key, es una recomendación así podrás obtener los elementos, y es una buena práctica para react,